# Unbound value for variable in ocaml method. Trying to print first 8 elements of array

Tags: debugging, ocaml

I'm trying to write a method which will allow me to print out positions of a chess game for the top 8 positions.

I have a val mutable initial which is an array of 32 entries,each containing chesspiece * chesscolor * chessposition.

The chessposition is defined as:

```
chess_position = Alive of chessletter * int | Dead;;
```

Im trying to print out the positions on the first row of the board for now.

I have the following code:

```
class chess =
    object
     val mutable initial = ([|Rook,Black,Alive(A,8); (*... *)|])

    method print = 
        for i = 0 to i = 7 do
            for j = 0 to j = 32 do
    if initial.(j) = (Pawn,White,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="P" else
    if initial.(j) = (Pawn,Black,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="p" else
    if initial.(j) = (Rook,White,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="R" else
    if initial.(j) = (Rook,Black,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="r" else
    if initial.(j) = (Knight,White,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="N" else
    if initial.(j) = (Knight,Black,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="n" else
    if initial.(j) = (Bishop,White,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="B" else
    if initial.(j) = (Bishop,Black,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="b" else
    if initial.(j) = (Queen,White,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="Q" else
    if initial.(j) = (Queen,Black,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="q" else
    if initial.(j) = (King,White,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="K" else
    if initial.(j) = (King,Black,Alive(A,i)) then tmp1="k" else
                tmp1=".";
                print_string tmp1;
            done
        done
end
```

In the case of normal chess starting positions where the row is white,this should print out:

```
RNBQKBNR
```

I'm getting an error of unbound value i and i cant understand why. 
On a side note,any advice on classes and methods is appreciated since i'm trying to learn this and currently suck at it.

Comment: (In the future it would be best to copy/paste the exact error message that you're seeing rather than just describing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
    for i = 0 to i = 7 do
```

is not legitimate. It parses as this:

```
for i = 0 to (i = 7) do
```

The second expression compares `i` against 7 for equality. But at that point there is no `i` defined yet. `i` is only defined in the body of the `for` loop.

You want to say:

```
for i = 1 to 7 do
```